# Extracting time from character string

Tags: r

is there any possibility to get time only from character string like "2021-09-13T16:40"?

I get it from lubridate or hms but my question is if I can get it with **base** R only.

I don't want to use format() because I want to have it with **class: "hms"      "difftime".**

Thank you

Comment: `sub(".*T", "", string)`

Comment: For clarification, you want your final output to be a class of `"hms" "difftime"`, but you only want to use base R? If I understand correctly, you'll need to at least load the [`hms`](https://hms.tidyverse.org/reference/hms.html) package to convert objects to `hms` objects.

Comment: Yes, I need a class of "hms" "difftime", which I can get with hms. So as I understand it is not possible with base R?

Comment: Yes, if you want an object to be a class of `hms`, you'll need to at least load the `hms` library, so what you want is not available in base R alone.

Comment: @jrcalabrese, you don't need `hms` loaded to create `"hms"` objects.  The S3 system in R is very loose (i.e. not strict).  All you need is to explicitly set the class.  You only need the package loaded when you want to use methods from it.

Comment: @jrcalabrese Yes, one does need to use `class<-` but one must first create the proper ‘difftime’ object for that coercion.

Answer (score 2):

Since the "hms" class is built with similar structure to items of class "difftime", even inheriting from that class, you can first build a "difftime"-classed item and then coerce its class to `c("hms", "difftime")`. The units parameter **must** be given as 'secs'  because the "hms" class does not support other units.

```
library(hms)  # to see how it encodes and labels data
?`hms-package`
test <- as_hms(Sys.time())
str(test)
#>  'hms' num 09:58:31.38673
#>  - attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"

dput(test)
#> structure(35911.3867301941, units = "secs", class = c("hms", 
#> "difftime"))

# So we need to build a difftime object with seconds units

z <- "2021-09-13T16:40"

zdt  <- strptime(z, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")

# Subtract the datetime value at midnight from the starting value and
# make it have a class of c("hms", "difftime")

# So subtract the value from midnight of the same day
dzdt <- difftime( zdt ,strptime(z, "%Y-%m-%d") , units="secs")
# Then coerce
class(dzdt)<- c("hms", "difftime")
# Now it will be recognized by the `print.hms` function
dzdt

# 16:40:00  # printed with the print method for "hms" objects

dput(dzdt)
#> structure(60000, class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")
```

Created on 2023-02-08 with reprex v2.0.2

Comment: It might be good solution for me but as an output I get 00:00:00.

Comment: I had erroneously put in `strftime` when it should have been `zdt  <- strptime(z, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")`. Try it now.  ( I copied from the wrong section of my console record. I had later corrected that error.)

Comment: @IRTFM:  preventing that kind of error is why the `reprex` package exists!

Comment: @user2554330 I see the other two answerers used it. Unfortunately they gave the wrong answers. The package doesn’t check the semantics. Only the syntax. Kind of like ChatGPT in that respect.

Comment: No, it just stops people from posting non-reproducible answers, as yours still is, because you don't load the `hms` package.  The result you get without that is `Time difference of 60000 secs`, not what you show.

Comment: I think the reason I got that is because I _did_ load pkg :hms. That’s one way to demonstrate that an equivalent data object can be delivered without using functions from that package. I needed to load it to figure out the structure of the desired result. I didn’t detach the namespace afterwards.

Comment: Yes, *you* loaded it, but you didn't show that in your answer.  The goal should be to post things that will give the same results for other people.

Comment: @user2554330   SO provides the ability to edit answers. Have at it.

Comment: @IRTFM, I think a change to make your answer reproducible would violate the "don't change the intention of the author" rule.

Comment: @user2554330 : I tried to submit the edited code to `reprex()` and was getting errors that correctly identified missing  octothorpes, but then after all the needed octothorpes were inserted eventually said: "This reprex appears to crash R. Call `reprex()` again with
  `std_out_err = TRUE` to get more info."  Attempting to follow those instructions was entirely uninformative. The code ran fine in an Rstudio console session.

Comment: The problem was the line beginning `#-`, which apparently has some special meaning to `knitr`, which is used by `reprex`.  If you remove that line, you get more understandable issues: `z` is used without being defined.

Comment: @user2554330 So the `z` object was supposed to be the input `"2021-09-13T16:40"`. When I fix that omission I now get a  reprex "rendering" error: `unexpected SPECIAL
17: 
18: zdt  <- strptime(z, "%Y-%m-%dT%` with the "arrow" indicating that the dash-pct-"d" is location of the unexpected special. The `reprex()` rendering process seems extraordinarily fragile.

Comment: I finally got `reprex()` to run the code and it's pasted in. It was rather painful. The error messages were obscure to me and didn't fit with my usual debugging strategies.

Comment: @IRTFM:  I don't generally have any of the problems you had.  My workflow:  highlight the code to use, Cmd-C to copy it to the clipboard (or Ctrl-C if not on Mac), run `reprex::reprex()`, paste the clipboard result into SO.  It saves me a lot of time.  I know it works more easily in RStudio than outside of it, so I assume you're not using RStudio, but I think some of the issues were just bad luck, since you were starting with comments that had been manually entered.  Starting with code with informative comments (not commented output) works great.

Comment: Your guess incorrect. I am currently using a recently updated version of Rstudio on an aging Linux version (Ubuntu 18.04). I also sometimes run either R.app or Rstudio on a Mac when traveling. I think that my managing to get not one but 3 different ways to crash the reprex-ed spawned R instances is rather damning. If I were being forced to use it, I might be sending issues to the Github site: https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex/issues, but I'm not being forced to use it, so maybe someone else will take the time.  I also see that SO is not keeping a faithful record of the edits to this answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```r
library(stringr)
library(hms)
library(lubridate)

string <- "2021-09-13T16:40"
hms::as_hms(as.POSIXct(str_extract(string,'(?<=T).*'), format='%H:%M'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
16:40:00
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for a non-tidyverse solution ... ???

Comment: Yes, only with base.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strptime` first to get the right format and after that use `strftime` to get the time you want:

```r
string <- "2021-09-13T16:40"
strftime(strptime(string, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), '%H:%M')
#> [1] "16:40"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, it is character.